# Alterar branch de origem

Tags: git, versionamento

Tem alguma forma de alterar a branch de origem da minha branch atual?

Ex.: Criei uma nova branch a partir da branch A, mas em determinado momento, percebi que deveria ter criado a partir da branch B e não da A. Tem alguma forma de alterar?

Comment: Você já trabalhou em cima dessa nova branch?

Comment: Ai depende. Qual seria o impacto de um merge da branch B na A? Uma solução seria você fazer o merge da branch B na branch nova, que é basicamente a branch A mais as suas alterações.

Comment: A branch A é mais recente e não pode ser mergeada para dentro da branch B (embora o contrário pode ser feito). E sim, já trabalhei na branch nova.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente da seguinte forma:

Crie um novo *branch* com origem no *branch* **B**, chamaremos ele de *branch* **D**

Volte para o *branch* que tem **A** como origem (É o *branch* que você já trabalhou, chamaremos ele de **C**) e dê um reset especificando o último *commit* que antecede seu trabalho, após isso, efetue o `git stash` para salvar temporariamente suas modificações.

Entre no *branch* **D** e execute o comando `git stash pop`, para recuperar as modificações que foram feitas no diretório de trabalho quando estava no *branch* **C**.

Após isso, resolva eventuais conflitos, adicione os arquivos na *staging area* e realize o *commit*, com isso seu novo *branch* **D**, tem **B** como origem e também as alterações que foram feitas quando se utilizava o *branch* **C**.